Unreliable and missing results Pandas Concat with Flattening a df column and merging with the original df
1I have a df that has a column with values
{'account': ['xxxx'], 'ip': ['2604:3d09:ae82:6600::'], 'UserAgent': []}
that I flatten with flatten_df=pd.json_normalize(column) and then concatenate with respective rows of the original dataframe using pd.concat([df,flatten_df],ignore_index=True,axis=1)
the lengths of the 2 dfs are same
enter image description here

I have tried resetting the index before concat and resetting the index after concat


Please read [mre] and Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question and [edit] your question with sample data as text that demonstrates the problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
